# WriteFile cancelled mid-way

Tags: go

I am currently writing some identifiers to a file, `last_imported.txt`. Every time I have imported an identifier, I want the file to contain only that.

It looks like `ioutil.WriteFile("last_import.txt", []byte(id), 0644)` would do the job, however it randomly leaves the file empty without writing the new identifier when I cancel the job while running, simulating a sudden crash.

I suspect that whenever it leaves it empty, it's because `f.write(data)` is never reached.

```
func WriteFile(filename string, data []byte, perm os.FileMode) error {
    f, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, perm)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    n, err := f.Write(data)
    if err == nil && n < len(data) {
        err = io.ErrShortWrite
    }
    if err1 := f.Close(); err == nil {
        err = err1
    }
    return err
}
```

How do I make sure that the file will not be left empty?

Comment: Why not to check you suspicion by adding logging?

Answer (score 2):

You should `Close()` the file using `defer`. This would flush buffer to file system.

See https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover

```
func WriteFile(filename string, data []byte, perm os.FileMode) error {
    f, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, perm)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer f.Close() // <-- ADD THIS to close file *************************

    n, err := f.Write(data)
    if err == nil && n < len(data) {
        err = io.ErrShortWrite
    }
    if err1 := f.Close(); err == nil {
        err = err1
    }
    return err
}
```

Comment: The code I pasted is directly from the source code of Go (https://golang.org/src/io/ioutil/ioutil.go line 76)

Comment: Ops. I guess the problem should be in your code. Probably the WriteFile is never called? Add logs & post you own code & logs output.

Comment: It is called, I can run it many times cancelling at a random time, and it'll randomly leave the file empty. It works fine 9 out of 10 times.

Comment: So may be there is a flaw in the `ioutil.WriteFile` impementation?

Try to use proposed code and see if it fixes the issue? Let us know on result if you do that.